# Most efficient compression extremely large data set

Tags: linux, storage

I'm currently generating an extremely large data set on a remote HPC (high performace computer). We are talking about 3 TB at the moment, and it could reach up to **10 TB** once I'm done.

Each of the 450 000 files ranges from a few KB to about 100 MB and contains lines of integers with no repetitive/predictable patterns.  Moreover they are split among 150 folders (I use the path to classify them according to the input parameters). Now that *could* be fine, but my research group is technically limited to **1TB** of disk space on the remote server, although the admin are willing to close their eyes until the situation gets sorted out.

What would you recommend to compress such a dataset? 
A limitation is that tasks can't run more than 48 hours at a time on this computer. So long but efficient compression methods are possible only if 48 hours is enough... I really have no other options as neither me, neither my group own enough disk space on other machines.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, this a remote computer that runs on some variation of linux. All standard compression protocols are available. I don't have super user rights.

**EDIT2:** As request by Sergio, here is a sample output (first 10 lines of a files)

```
27 42 46 63 95 110 205 227 230 288 330 345 364 367 373 390 448 471 472 482 509 514 531 533 553 617 636 648 667 682 703 704 735 740 762 775 803 813 882 915 920 936 939 942 943 979 1018 1048 1065 1198 1219 1228 1513 1725 1888 1944 2085 2190 2480 5371 5510 5899 6788 7728 9514 10382 11946 13063 13808 16070 23301 23511 24538 
93 94 106 143 157 164 168 181 196 293 299 334 369 372 439 457 508 527 547 557 568 570 573 592 601 668 701 704 799 838 848 870 875 882 890 913 953 959 1022 1024 1037 1046 1169 1201 1288 1615 1684 1771 2043 2204 2348 2387 2735 3149 4319 4890 4989 5321 5588 6453 7475 9277 9649 9654 11433 16966 
1463 
183 469 514 597 792 
25 50 143 152 205 244 253 424 433 446 461 476 486 545 552 570 632 642 647 665 681 682 718 735 746 772 792 811 830 851 891 903 925 1037 1115 1147 1171 1612 1979 2749 3074 3158 6042 12709 20571 20859 
24 30 86 312 726 875 1023 1683 1799 
33 36 42 65 110 112 122 227 241 262 274 284 305 328 353 366 393 414 419 449 462 488 489      514 635 690 732 744 767 772 812 820 843 844 855 889 893 925 936 939 981 1015 1020 1060 1064 1130 1174 1304 1393 1477 1939 2004 2200 2205 2208 2216 2234 3284 4456 5209 6810 6834 8067 10811 10895 12771 15291 
157 761 834 875 1001 2492 
21 141 146 169 181 256 266 337 343 367 397 402 405 433 454 466 513 527 656 684 708 709 732 743 811 883 913 938 947 986 987 1013 1053 1190 1215 1288 1289 1333 1513 1524 1683 1758 2033 2684 3714 4129 6015 7395 8273 8348 9483 23630 
1253
```

All integers are separated by one whitespace, and each line corresponds to a given element. I use implicit line numbers to store this information, because my data is assosiative i.e. the 0th element is associated to elements 27 42 46 63 110.. etc. I believe that there is no extra information whatsoever.

Comment: In WinXP: `Right Click -> Send to zip ...` ;)

Comment: Yeah, I wish it could be that simple...

Comment: What is that, communication tracking data from NSA?

Comment: Check that, hope it helps.  http://www.maximumcompression.com/ However, I think the best compression strategy depends on your application

Comment: Nop, I'm characterising a 5 parameters stochastic process, which means that I have to simulate it for a decently fine meshing of the 5 parameter space, at least a thousand time per set of parameters. Each iteration is stored in a set of 3 fairly large files..  so it grows fast.

Comment: me too.. (I must admit)

Comment: AFAIK the the best on linux is tar bz2 .. but maybe there are already better ones

Comment: Check lzma http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/lzma-better-compression-than-bzip2-on-unix-linux/

Comment: Any chance you can change the way to save the file from your program? in that case, can you copy and paste at least 1 line of output from your program? Probably you can save a lot of space by just changing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points that may help:

- It looks like your numbers are sorted. If this is always the case, then it will be more efficient to compress the **differences** between adjacent numbers rather than the numbers themselves (since the differences will be somewhat smaller on average)
- There are good ways of encoding small integer values in binary format, that are probably better than encoding them in text format. See the technique used by Google in their protocol buffers: (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)
- Once you have applied the above techniques, then zipping / some standard form of compression should improve everything even further.

Comment: The difference of adjacent number bit is very interesting! Sure, it will involve extra computation when analysing the data, but it will help reduce the size of files tremendously. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is some research done at this [LINK](http://bashitout.com/2009/08/30/Linux-Compression-Comparison-GZIP-vs-BZIP2-vs-LZMA-vs-ZIP-vs-Compress.html) that breaks down the pro/cons of using `gzip`, `bzip2`, and `lzma`.  Hopefully this can let you make an informed decision on your best approach.

Answer (score 1):

All your numbers seem to be increasing in size (each line). A rather common approach in database technology would be to only store the **size difference**, making a line like

```
24 30 86 312 726 875 1023 1683 1799
```

to something like

```
6 56 226 414 149 148 660 116
```

Other lines of your example would even show more benefit, as the differences are smaller. This also works when the numbers decrease in-between, but you have to be able to deal with negative differences then.

Second thing to do would be changing the **encoding**. While compression will reduce this overhead, you're currently using 8 bit per digit, whereas you only need 4 bit of those (0-9, space as divisor). Implementing your own "4 bit character set" will already cut your storage requirements to half of the current size! In the end, this would be some kind of binary encoding of numbers of arbitrary length.